# Crashlytics Mapping files not getting generated

Tags: android, firebase, jenkins, proguard, crashlytics

I have enabled proguard using `minifyEnabled true` and trying to create build from jenkins. But while creating apk from jenkins I am getting following build error.

```
> Task :app:packageUat
> Task :app:uploadCrashlyticsMappingFileUat FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:uploadCrashlyticsMappingFileUat'.
> Crashlytics could not find the resource file generated by Google Services. You may need to execute the :process<Variant>GoogleServices Task. Please check your Firebase project configuration (https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup).
```

I am using FCM and Crashlytics Google services in my application. I have not included `google-service.json` but initializing runtime. Here is firebase initialization code :

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(mAppContext, new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setProjectId(BuildConfig.PROJECT_ID)
            .setApiKey(BuildConfig.API_KEY)
            .setApplicationId(BuildConfig.FCM_APPLICATION_ID)
            .setGcmSenderId(BuildConfig.GCM_SENDER_ID)
            .build());

    FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
```

Following command I am using on jenkins to create build :

```
clean
assemble${Build}
```

Here is my uat build configuration  :

```
uat {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.uat
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        buildConfigField "String", 'API_KEY', API_KEY
        buildConfigField "String", 'FCM_APPLICATION_ID', FCM_APPLICATION_ID
        buildConfigField "String", 'PROJECT_ID', PROJECT_ID
        buildConfigField "String", 'GCM_SENDER_ID', GCM_SENDER_ID

    }
```

I can not include google-service.json in my project because of security issue. Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

It clearly tells you that it expects it in the `res` directory:

> Crashlytics could not find the **resource file** generated by Google Services.

The XML file would look alike [this](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin#processing_the_json_file)... but why not simply provide `google-services.json` at build time? This is probably less effort than generating the XML file from environmental variables (which is basically nothing else than the plugin does).

And actually... the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup?authuser=0#add-config-file) reads:

> The Firebase config file contains unique, but non-secret identifiers for your project.

Comment: Problem with google-service.json is that anyone will have access to keys if anyone got access to code. that's why we are injecting it from jenkins.

Comment: Just add a build step, shell script, then inject the whole file as here-doc. And haven't you read my answer? There is absolutely nothing "secret" about this file, anybody who can decompile the app has access to these strings. This is not a service-account config file, which would hold SSH keys.

Comment: Hi @Martin I got your point but is really possible to configure proguard in project without having google-services.json?